# Survfit and covariables in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Using the code below, I have managed to create a univariate survival analysis from `ggsurvplot` using the `survminer` package.

I have been able to generate a univariate analysis with cox regression and plot using `ggsurvplot`, but when I run my multivariate analysis (that includes the covariables: `age + sex + smoking_status + match_RF_HF + match_RF_AMI + match_RF_T2D + match_RF_HTA + match_RF_MI`, I get the same table risk table with the same values, whilst the risk table should be different between the univariate and the multivariate analyses.

Here is the code to get the univariate analysis:

```
# your custom theme; unchanged
custom_theme <- function(){
  theme_survminer() %+replace%
    theme(
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"),
      plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.4)
    )
}

# Apply filters to create the filtered dataset
#filtered_data <- df_ukb %>%
 # filter(is.na(time_diff_MACE_months) | time_diff_MACE_months >= 0) %>%  # remove time diff negative
  #filter(time_diff_MACE_months <= N * 12) %>%  ## remove time diff more than N follow up
  #filter(time_diff_MACE_months >= 1) %>% ## remove AF proc within 1 month after AF
  #filter(dateAF_plusNy <= Sys.Date())  ##remove N more than today

filtered_data <- df_ukb %>%
  filter(is.na(time_diff_MACE_months) | time_diff_MACE_months >= 0) %>%  # remove time diff negative
  filter(time_diff_MACE_months <= N * 12) %>%  ## remove time diff more than N follow up
  filter(time_diff_MACE_months >= 1) %>% ## remove AF proc within 1 month after AF
  filter(dateAF_plusNy <= Sys.Date())

## specific order
scoreMVPA_order <- c("no AF proc + inactive", "no AF proc + active", "AF proc + inactive", "AF proc + active")

filtered_data <-
  filtered_data %>% 
  mutate(scoreMVPA = fct_relevel(scoreMVPA,scoreMVPA_order))


# Create the formula
filtered_data$event <- filtered_data$match_MACE
filtered_data$event_followup <- filtered_data$time_diff_MACE_months
formula1 <- as.formula("Surv(event_followup, event) ~ scoreMVPA")

# Fit Cox proportional hazards model with reference group
cox1 <- coxph(Surv(event_followup, event) ~ scoreMVPA, data = filtered_data)

cox1 <- coxph(formula1, data = filtered_data)

cox1

coxP1 <- data.frame(summary(cox1)$coefficients)[,5]

coxP1

# Generate the confidence intervals and p-values with renamed scores
coxConf1 <- data.frame(summary(cox1)$conf.int) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(p = coxP1,
         p2 = case_when(
           round(p, 3) > p ~ '=',
           round(p, 3) < p ~ '=',
           round(p, 3) == p ~ '='
         ),
         p3 = ifelse(round(p, 2) == 1, T, F),
         tag = paste0(rowname %>% gsub("(\\D)(\\d)", "\\1 \\2", .),
                      ". HR ", exp.coef. %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      " (95% CI ",
                      lower..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "-", upper..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "), ",
                      ifelse(p < 0.001, "P<0.001",
                             ifelse(p >= 0.01 & p < 0.05, "P<0.05",
                                    ifelse(p >= 0.05, paste0("P", p2, sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", round(p, 2))),
                                           paste0("P", p2, sprintf(fmt = "%.3f", p))))))) %>%
  select(tag) %>%
  rename(new_variable_name = tag)

coxConf1$new_variable_name <- gsub("scoreMVPA", "", coxConf1$new_variable_name)

# Remove leading and trailing spaces
coxConf1$new_variable_name <- trimws(coxConf1$new_variable_name)

# Validate the result
coxConf1

# model to plot- 
###----
fit1 <- survfit(Surv(event_followup, event) ~ scoreMVPA, data = filtered_data)

# Generate the plot with the reordered legends
uni <- ggsurvplot(fit1,
                   data = uni_data,
                   test.for.trend = TRUE,
                   conf.int = FALSE,
                   censor = FALSE,
                   ggtheme = custom_theme(), 
                   legend = c(0.4, 0.25),
                   font.legend = c(size = 12),
                   legend.title = element_blank(),
                   legend.labs = c("no AF proc + inactive. ", unlist(coxConf1)),
                   xlab = "Follow-up (months)",
                   font.x = c(size = 12),
                   risk.table = T,
                   risk.table.side = "left",
                   risk.table.y.text = F,
                   risk.table.title = "Risk Table",
                   risk.table.col = 1,
                   ylab = "Free from MACE",
                   font.y = c(size = 12),
                   ylim = c(0, 1.05),
                   xlim = c(0, N * 12),
                   break.y.by = 0.2,
                   break.x.by = 6,
                   axes.offset = TRUE)
```

And the code for the multivariate analysis:

```
##MULTIVARIATE ANALYSIS
##covariables
# Define covariates: "age", "sex", "smoking_status", "match_RF_HF", "match_RF_AMI", "match_RF_T2D", "match_RF_HTA", "match_RF_MI"
covariates <- c("age", "sex", "smoking_status", "match_RF_HF", "match_RF_AMI", "match_RF_T2D", "match_RF_HTA", "match_RF_MI")

# Covariate formula
covariate_formula <- as.formula(paste("Surv(event_followup, event) ~ scoreMVPA +", paste(covariates, collapse = "+"))) ###I have tried to combine my covariates but I am not able to

# Apply filters in Cox proportional hazards model
cox2 <- coxph(Surv(event_followup, event) ~ age + sex + smoking_status + match_RF_HF + match_RF_AMI + match_RF_T2D + match_RF_HTA + match_RF_MI + strata(scoreMVPA),
                data=filtered_data)

coxP2 <- data.frame(summary(cox2)$coefficients)[,5]

#create theme
coxConf2 <- data.frame(summary(cox2)$conf.int) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(p = coxP2,
         p2 = case_when(
           round(p, 3) > p ~ '=',
           round(p, 3) < p ~ '=',
           round(p, 3) == p ~ '='
         ),
         p3 = ifelse(round(p, 2) == 1, T, F),
         tag = paste0(rowname %>% gsub("(\\D)(\\d)", "\\1 \\2", .),
                      ". HR ", exp.coef. %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      " (95% CI ",
                      lower..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "-", upper..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "), ",
                      ifelse(p < 0.001, "P<0.001",
                             ifelse(p >= 0.01 & p < 0.05, "P<0.05",
                                    ifelse(p >= 0.05, paste0("P", p2, sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", round(p, 2))),
                                           paste0("P", p2, sprintf(fmt = "%.3f", p))))))) %>%
  select(tag) %>%
  rename(new_variable_name = tag)

coxConf2$new_variable_name <- gsub("scoreMVPA", "", coxConf2$new_variable_name)

# Remove leading and trailing spaces
coxConf2$new_variable_name <- trimws(coxConf2$new_variable_name)

coxConf2 <- coxConf2 %>% slice(1:3)


##
survfit2 <- survfit(cox2)

# Generate the plot with the reordered legends
multi <- ggsurvplot(survfit2,
                   data = multi_data,
                   test.for.trend = TRUE,
                   conf.int = FALSE,
                   censor = FALSE,
                   ggtheme = custom_theme(), 
                   legend = c(0.4, 0.25),
                   font.legend = c(size = 12),
                   legend.title = element_blank(),
                   legend.labs = c("no AF proc + inactive. ", unlist(coxConf2)),
                   xlab = "Follow-up (months)",
                   font.x = c(size = 12),
                   risk.table = TRUE,
                   risk.table.side = "left",
                   risk.table.y.text = FALSE,
                   risk.table.title = "Risk Table",
                   risk.table.col = 1,
                   ylab = "Free from MACE",
                   font.y = c(size = 12),
                   ylim = c(0, 1.05),
                   xlim = c(0, N * 12),
                   break.y.by = 0.2,
                   break.x.by = 6,
                   axes.offset = TRUE)
```

Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
structure(list(sex = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"), age = c(41, 
58, 63, 65, 62, 66, 68, 48, 68, 59, 63, 67, 64, 66, 52, 52, 69, 
64, 61, 67, 65, 67, 61, 62, 58, 54, 53, 66, 67, 67, 64, 65, 64, 
69, 63, 51, 67, 65, 68, 64, 65, 58, 62, 65, 67, 63, 60, 52, 69, 
69, 54, 53, 55, 68, 61, 46, 67, 67, 57, 55, 61, 65, 61, 66, 48, 
47, 69, 55, 58, 69, 64, 53, 65, 64, 62, 68, 64, 65, 60, 58, 54, 
43, 51, 69, 60, 69, 70, 64, 59, 65, 61, 69, 67, 63, 69, 58, 55, 
61, 63, 64, 65, 69, 62, 69, 61, 65, 60, 53, 41, 56, 61, 65, 65, 
68, 65, 51, 69, 52, 61, 54, 44, 63, 55, 62, 62, 68, 54, 63, 41, 
69, 67, 50, 65, 60, 59, 67, 66, 61, 67, 47, 63, 66, 65, 64, 57, 
52, 65, 65, 60, 44, 48, 67, 43, 63, 46, 59, 63, 66, 67, 62, 62, 
59, 70, 64, 65, 63, 62, 62, 42, 60, 62, 61, 64, 61, 60, 68, 64, 
56, 66, 61, 69, 62, 58, 59, 60, 57, 69, 47, 69, 51, 43, 63, 63, 
64, 68, 64, 60, 70, 66, 62), smoking_status = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), match_MACE = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0), time_diff_MACE_months = c(72, 72, 28.4, 59.4, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 68.9, 11.4, 72, 72, 11.7, 7.8, 1.5, 72, 1.7, 16.8, 72, 
72, 72, 26.1, 72, 72, 62.3, 72, 72, 72, 38.9, 72, 72, 49.8, 72, 
72, 13, 26.4, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 18.8, 24, 49.9, 25.1, 72, 16.4, 
72, 27, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 3.6, 72, 72, 72, 72, 40.8, 
72, 1.6, 72, 72, 69, 3.4, 72, 28.1, 72, 72, 52.8, 72, 39.6, 72, 
59.9, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 6.8, 72, 37.9, 72, 9.3, 18.7, 5.9, 
72, 37.1, 72, 72, 5.9, 72, 72, 20.4, 45.6, 68.5, 72, 72, 25.4, 
72, 72, 18.5, 72, 72, 72, 10.1, 24, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 11.3, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 41.6, 72, 72, 72, 66.6, 24.1, 72, 72, 8, 72, 
1.2, 72, 72, 72, 2.1, 30.6, 72, 10, 72, 55.5, 20.9, 67, 11.7, 
4, 72, 18, 14, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 7.7, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 64.3, 56.8, 2.6, 72, 3.9, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 37.9, 22.6, 72, 72, 30.4, 72, 72, 72, 72, 34.5, 72, 8, 72, 
24.3, 72, 13.5, 9.3, 12, 72, 3, 1.3, 72, 72, 72, 72), match_RF_stroke = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), match_RF_HF = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), match_RF_AMI = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), match_RF_T2D = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), match_RF_HTA = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), match_RF_MI = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), scoreMVPA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L), levels = c("no AF proc + inactive", "no AF proc + active", 
"AF proc + inactive", "AF proc + active"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I would read this on how to perform adjusted KM curves: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/adjcurve.pdf

Comment: Yes, I have tried this but unfortunately, I am still getting the output for all the covariables, while I am only want the main variable (scoreMPA) which has 4 groups. Thanks!

Comment: There are 3 methods in that paper discussing how to do adjusted survival curves, which ones did you try?

Comment: I have tried this `fit2 <- survfit(covariate_formula, data = filtered_data)` based on the 5.2 section but it provides me the full list of covariates, while I would like only the scoreMPA data. Let me know if you can be helpful here. Thanks

Comment: in addition, I am using `ggsurv` for the plot

Comment: does the answer below solve your issue?

Comment: I have tried, but I have not been able to while using my own data. However, I have updated my question and provided some dataset and made the question clearer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to obtain a marginal adjusted survival curve using a cox model. You could either use the `ggadjustedcurves` function from the `survminer` package, or you could use the `adjustedCurves` package if you also need confidence intervals to go with it.

Creating a survival curve using this method is absolutely valid, but it is impossible to get an "adjusted risk table" then. There is no such thing. It is not a Kaplan-Meier estimate anymore and as such does not use numbers at risk etc.

The only form of adjusted risk table that does exist is if you use inverse probability of treatment weighting to obtain the adjusted survival curves (as described in https://robindenz1.github.io/adjustedCurves/reference/surv_iptw_km.html). That method actually weights the number of events and number of risks, making it possible to obtain the "adjusted risk table". If you use the `adjustedCurves` package, that table will be included in the output object but it will still not be possible to directly plot it. To me it does not really seem all that important though.

Answer (score 0):

In the example below I am using the `trial` dataset from `gtsummary` so you can follow along. First you can make a cox model with covariates, in my example I will want to show the adjusted curves for treatment (`trt`) adjusted by `age` and `grade`. In order to get these adjusted estimates you have to provide `survfit` with a new `data.frame` in the `newdata` argument.  I create a new dataset called `newdf` that has both treatment levels, the median age for both groups and one grade level. You will see that `newsurv` has two estimates this is one for each level of treatment adjusted for `age` (at the median) and `grade I` (reference level in cox model). From here I do some data manipulation to get the data in the format I want so I can pass it to `ggplot2`.

```
library(survival)
library(gtsummary)
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mod1 <- coxph(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ trt + age + grade, data = trial)

newdf <- data.frame(trt = c("Drug A", "Drug B"), age=47, grade = "I") 


newsurv <- survfit(mod1, newdata = newdf) 
            

newsurvdf <- broom::tidy(newsurv) %>% 
              pivot_longer(cols = c("estimate.1",  "estimate.2" )) %>% 
              mutate(name = ifelse(name == "estimate.1", "Drug A","Drug B"))

ggplot(newsurvdf)+
        geom_step(aes(x = time, y  = value, color = name))
```

### Edit using your data.

please note your test data didn't have event_followup or event in the data.frame I had to use other variables so remember to change that back. The process with your data is the same as the process I did with the toy data set I used.

```
# Apply filters in Cox proportional hazards model
cox2 <- coxph(Surv(time_diff_MACE_months, match_MACE) ~ age + sex + smoking_status + match_RF_HF + match_RF_AMI + match_RF_T2D + match_RF_HTA + match_RF_MI + strata(scoreMVPA),
              data=df)
newdf <- data.frame(age = median(df$age,na.rm=TRUE), sex = "Female",
                    smoking_status = 0, 
                    match_RF_HF =0, match_RF_AMI =0, match_RF_T2D =0, 
                    match_RF_HTA =0, match_RF_MI=0 ,
                    scaoreMVPA = c("no AF proc + inactive", "no AF proc + active",
                                   "AF proc + inactive",   
                                    "AF proc + active" ))


newsurv <- survfit(cox2, newdata = newdf) 


newsurvdf <- broom::tidy(newsurv) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("estimate.1",  "estimate.2", "estimate.3","estimate.4" )) %>% 
  select(name, value, strata, time)


ggplot(newsurvdf)+
  geom_step(aes(x = time, y  = value, color = strata))
```

Comment: Thank you for that Mike. I have updated the question to have a better understanding. Hope it helps.

Comment: any help Mike please since I updated the code ? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Mike, the plot is very well generated. However, as mentioned in my question, how do get the risk table for this new adjusted plot ?

Comment: the adjusted survival analysis doesn't really have number at risk or number of events, you are simply expressing the cox model at specific levels of the independent variables in the model over time . They do not correspond to the actual data, that is why we pass in the `newdf`